# Fetch throwing error with 302 in componentdidmount react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am having an issue in using the fetch method in the componentDidMount method when an api call is redirecting and returning the response. Initial 302 response is trying to get processed in then method after fetch and throwing a JSON.parse: unexpected end of data at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data. Any suggestion on how I can solve this issue ?

```
componentDidMount(){
            let config = {
                method: 'GET',
                mode: 'no-cors',
                redirect:'follow',
                cache: 'default',
                headers: new Headers({
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
                })
            };

         fetch("ACTUAL_URL",config)
         .then(response => response.text())
         .then( val => JSON.parse(val))
         .then(response => {
                    this.setState({val:response.json()})
            })
    }
```

API CALL response
-302 
- 200

Comment: note: `response.json()` is a Promise, so that's probably not what you want to do anyway - if something is trying to JSON.parse that `val`, it'll be trying to parse the string `"[object Promise]"` - clearly not valid JSON. If that is indeed the problem, then read [how to use fetch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch)

Comment: 302 is returning a undefined object and trying to convert that json is causing an issue.

Comment: Yes. That is another mistake in your code

Answer (score 1):

fetch only rejects in case of network error . For other cases you have to use 
  the ok method

```
fetch("ACTUAL_URL",config)
         .then(function(data){
              if (!data.ok) {
               throw Error(data);
              }
         }).then(response => response.text())
         .then( val => JSON.parse(val))
         .then(response => {
                    this.setState({val:response.json()})
         }).catch(function(error){
           // handle the 302 error here
         })
```